# Hide/Show elements by clicking only one button

Tags: javascript, html

Right know the code is working great but really what I want is to make the button with text "hide" to change that text to "show" but only it should happen after I click the button with text "hide" and after I click that button the text content hides and only it remains the button with text "show" and when I click show I want the code to show again.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myList li");

  for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var item = listItems[i];

    item.querySelector(".hide").onclick = function(e) {
      var img = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("img"),
        header = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("h3"),
        elemA = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("a"),
        elemP = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("p"),
        span = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("span");

      img.style.display = "none";
      header.style.display = "none";
      elemA.style.display = "none";
      elemP.style.display = "none";
      span.style.display = "none";
    };
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>
      <img class="img" src="gta.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      <h3>
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCFR26D5ofA" class="name" target="_blank">BOOM AND DOOM</a>
    </h3>
      <p>
        By: Zerkaa
      </p>
      <span>
     129,702 views - 2 months ago 
    </span>
      <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="img" src="gta.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      <h3> 
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yw3tTTIZyf4" class="name" target="_blank">CLOWN DEATH RUN</a>
    </h3>
      <p>
        By: KSI
      </p>
      <span>
     176,977 - 3 months ago
    </span>
      <button class="hide clicked" onclick="showhide()">Hide</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="img" src="gta.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      <h3> 
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXLxuosFAc" class="name" target="_blank">BREACH WALL ADVENTURE</a>
    </h3>
      <p>
        By: MM7GAMES
      </p>
      <span>
     135,782 - 4 months ago
    </span>
      <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="img" src="gta.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      <h3>
     <a  href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBjknMuFt7A&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=3" class="name" target"=_blank">FINISH LINE TUNNEL</a>
    </h3>
      <p>
        By: W2S
      </p>
      <span>
     104,169 views 5 months ago
    </span>
      <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="img" src="gta.jpg" width="250" height="250">
      <h3>
     <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukxhgumzKG4&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=7" class="name" target="_blank">INSANE MOUNTAIN RAMP</a>
    </h3>
      <p>
        By: TBJZL
      </p>
      <span>
     181,137 views 6 months ago
    </span>
      <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you should try to isolate the problems to few and post all relevant code only, and not just dump all css,js, and html files. this way you will get answer.

Comment: AngularJS would make your life easier, its very simple to deal with things like this. Just a suggestion.

Comment: wont advice to add angularjs lib just for toggling functionality

Comment: Can you include a working JSFiddle?

Comment: by the way, you have an error in your 4th `li > h3 > a` `target` attribute

Comment: @DanielJacobson is this what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what you want. You want the contents to `hide` or `display` accordingly and the text of the `button` to be 'Hide' or 'Show' accordingly. Am I right? If yes, then I've created a JSFiddle, check it out, its working -
http://jsfiddle.net/g6kjrc08/

Answer (score 2):

Try using a little CSS to make your life easier.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myList > li");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(listItems, function (item) {
    item.querySelector(".hide").addEventListener("click", function () {
      item.classList.toggle("hidden");

      if (this.textContent === "Hide") {
        this.textContent = "Show";
      } else {
        this.textContent = "Hide";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden :not(.hide) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCFR26D5ofA" target="_blank">BOOM AND DOOM</a></h3>

      <p>By: Zerkaa</p><span>129,702 views - 2 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yw3tTTIZyf4" target="_blank">CLOWN DEATH RUN</a></h3>

      <p>By: KSI</p><span>176,977 - 3 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXLxuosFAc" target="_blank">BREACH WALL ADVENTURE</a></h3>

      <p>By: MM7GAMES</p><span>135,782 - 4 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBjknMuFt7A&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=3" target="_blank">FINISH LINE TUNNEL</a></h3>

      <p>By: W2S</p><span>104,169 views 5 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukxhgumzKG4&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=7" target="_blank">INSANE MOUNTAIN RAMP</a></h3>

      <p>By: TBJZL</p><span>181,137 views 6 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or if you only want to use JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function () {

  var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myList > li");

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(listItems, function (item) {
    var descendants = item.querySelectorAll(":not(.hide)");

    item.querySelector(".hide").addEventListener("click", function () {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(descendants, function (descendant) {
        if (descendant.style.display === "none") {
          descendant.style.display = "";
        } else {
          descendant.style.display = "none";
        }
      });

      if (this.textContent === "Hide") {
        this.textContent = "Show";
      } else {
        this.textContent = "Hide";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="myList">
    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCFR26D5ofA" target="_blank">BOOM AND DOOM</a></h3>

      <p>By: Zerkaa</p><span>129,702 views - 2 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yw3tTTIZyf4" target="_blank">CLOWN DEATH RUN</a></h3>

      <p>By: KSI</p><span>176,977 - 3 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EXLxuosFAc" target="_blank">BREACH WALL ADVENTURE</a></h3>

      <p>By: MM7GAMES</p><span>135,782 - 4 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBjknMuFt7A&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=3" target="_blank">FINISH LINE TUNNEL</a></h3>

      <p>By: W2S</p><span>104,169 views 5 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img class="img" height="250" src="gta.jpg" width="250">

      <h3><a class="name" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukxhgumzKG4&list=PLu1nstonJHbQGN0kQJ-UFrMDc9fwMpeIS&index=7" target="_blank">INSANE MOUNTAIN RAMP</a></h3>

      <p>By: TBJZL</p><span>181,137 views 6 months ago</span> <button class="hide clicked">Hide</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly too but I am trying only js code but thanks because from you I learned how I can use css for hide/show elements.

Comment: The code is in JS, some advanced coding for advanced or professional programmers.

Comment: @EndritShala I added a JS-only solution as well

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks man I appreciate that you are helping me so much.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this code it's more maintainable, modular, and compact...

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/shcr2w4s/

```
var btns = toArray(document.getElementsByClassName('hide'));

btns.forEach(function (x) {
    var ele = x.parentElement.querySelector('.cont');
    var style = ['block','none'],
        text = ['Hide', 'Show'],
        n = 0;
    x.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        n = (n==1)?0:1;
        x.innerText = text[n];
        ele.style.display = style[n];
    });

});


function toArray(x) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) arr.push(x[i]);
    return arr;
}
```

**also note change in html structure, it's better to hide one element instead of hiding every single element. Not only it's more error prone, but not all elements can be brought back to original state with display:block, as some might be inline-block, table, inline etc.**

### Had you used jquery this could've been done like this

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/shcr2w4s/1/

```
var text = ['Hide', 'Show'];

$('button[class="hide"]').click(function () {
    var t = $(this);
    t.siblings('.cont').toggle();
    t.text(text[(text.indexOf(t.text()) + 1) % text.length]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me another way of doing this and I will keep in my mind what you wrote about that error prone.

Comment: "Not only it's more error prone, but not all elements can be brought back to original state with display:block" ... that's why you use `ele.style.display = "" ` to bring it back to original `display`.

Comment: didn't think of that, but even this has a gotcha, for example if some other script set the style in js, meaning inline css, then when my script over rides it, i better make it so my script memorizes the state that i have over ridden. And even there is a matter of some other script changing state while my script did something..

Comment: say element was inline, i replace it with none & memorize the inline part. then some other script set it to inline-block. Then times come for my script to show element, it sets it to inline as it had memorized. True show and hide would result in inline-block. Therefore either just plan it out carefully, isolate a div and use it for this purpose only, or use css class to show and hide, this way you can only remove your code and not overrides others'

Answer (score 0):

For the changing text, why don't use Inner.html ?

Like putting `this.innerHTML = 'Show';` in your `item.querySelector(".hide").onclick` function

Or include Jquery to use .html()

Comment: This doesn't help me that much but thanks again for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "hidden" attribute (i.e `<p hidden = 'true'></p>`) to the elements that you want to toggle hidden or visible, and then use `element.setAttribute("hidden", true);` to hide the element and use the value 'false' to show that element again. I would make a function for both show and hide so that you can just call the function in your .onclicks to make your life much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think u want something like this.

```js
$('#toggle-Button').on('click', function(){
  if( $(this).val() == 'show' )
    $(this).val('hide');
  else
    $(this).val('show');
  
  $('#some-div').toggle();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="toggle-Button" type="button" value="hide" />

<div id="some-div">
  some text
</div>
```

Comment: No I don't want something like this. And I didn't tag jQuery.

Comment: i didn't knew jquery is not javascript, and this is not same as ur example plus what u asked in question, change hide to show vice versa. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this js code

var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#myList li");

for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
    var item = listItems[i];

```
item.querySelector(".hide").onclick = function (e) {
    if(this.innerText == "Hide"){
        this.innerText="Show";
    var img = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("img"),
        header = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("h3"),
        elemA = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("a"),
        elemP = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("p"),
        span = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("span");

    img.style.display = "none";
    header.style.display = "none";
    elemA.style.display = "none";
    elemP.style.display = "none";
    span.style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
        this.innerText="Hide";
    var img = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("img"),
        header = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("h3"),
        elemA = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("a"),
        elemP = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("p"),
        span = e.target.parentNode.querySelector("span");

    img.style.display = "inline";
    header.style.display = "block";
    elemA.style.display = "block";
    elemP.style.display = "block";
    span.style.display = "inline";
    }
};
```

}